# Error: Cursor' object has no attribute '_last_executed

Tags: python, django, string, database-cursor, rawsql

I have this cursor

```
cursor.execute("SELECT price FROM Items WHERE itemID = ( 
                  SELECT item_id FROM Purchases 
                  WHERE purchaseID = %d AND customer_id = %d)", 
                  [self.purchaseID, self.customer])
```

I get this error

```
'Cursor' object has no attribute '_last_executed'
```

But when I try this:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT price FROM Items WHERE itemID = ( 
                  SELECT item_id FROM Purchases 
                  WHERE purchaseID = 1 AND customer_id = 1)", 
                  )
```

there is no error. How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you finally get it working?

Comment: I had the same error message, but using the ORM. It turned out to be charset problem solved with encapsulating my string with unicode(). I know it does not answer your question, but it might fit with others that land upon this page in search for answers.

Answer (score 8):

I encountered this problem too. I changed the %d to %s, and it is solved. Wish this is useful for you.

Comment: This worked for me.  I guess you have to pass `%s` even for ints.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you are not making substitutions properly in your select string. From docs:

```
def execute(self, query, args=None):

    """Execute a query.

    query -- string, query to execute on server
    args -- optional sequence or mapping, parameters to use with query.

    Note: If args is a sequence, then %s must be used as the
    parameter placeholder in the query. If a mapping is used,
    %(key)s must be used as the placeholder.

    Returns long integer rows affected, if any

    """
```

So, it should be:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT price FROM Items WHERE itemID = ( 
              SELECT item_id FROM Purchases 
              WHERE purchaseID = ? AND customer_id = ?)", 
              (self.purchaseID, self.customer))
```

Comment: what version of python are you using?

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that you are using '%d'. When you use '%' in SQL, the execute will interpret the '%' as the format. You should write your statement like this:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT price FROM Items WHERE itemID = ( 
                SELECT item_id FROM Purchases 
                WHERE purchaseID = %%d AND customer_id = %%d)", 
                [self.purchaseID, self.customer])
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but documentation for [raw queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly) says to use one `%` for substitution.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your SQL package, you may need to use `cursor.statement` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me using double %%

```
  "SELECT  title, address from table t1, table t2 on t1.id=t2.id where t1.title like '%%Brink%%' "
```

Comment: For the person who downvoted this, care to explain why?

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db import connection
print(connection.queries)
```

The code above should display all the requeries that are executed on the request.